# Does binomial regression weight some observations more heavily than other?

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I am performing a quasibinomial regression, where each subject has an unfixed number of trials. So one subject may have had 5 trials while another had 90. In R the regression equation follows:

glm(success_percent ~ x1 + x2 +..., data = data, family=quasibinomial, weights=trials)

I am unfamiliar with how a glm handles these weights. Is a subject with 10 trials contributing twice as much to the model as a subject with 5? Or is the number of trials just used to account for within-subject variability?